# Linux does not communicate to Windows subinterface

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking

I set my NIC on *Windows* so that I have two interfaces:

- one (the first one) has IP 192.168.0.5
- the other one has IP 10.10.10.1.

On a *Linux* machine I set an interface to 10.10.10.2. On another *Linux* machine I set the interface to 10.10.10.3. And tried to ping those machines. Here is the result. *Linux* to *Linux* is ok. *Windows* to *Linux* also is ok. But *Linux* to *Windows* does not work.

Can you help me on getting the communication between *Linux* and *Windows*? What should I do for this? I have to mention that those machines are connected through a switch.

If you need any details, ask me please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the second interface bridged?

Comment: @Colyn1337 No. See my edited title again please!

Comment: Well, the obvious: did you check that the Windows Firewall is disabled, and no "security" software on the Win machine is intervening? And did you check that the 10.10.10.1 interface is live? Also, try using something other than 10.10.10.1 as Windows does this funky thing sometimes with the address ending in .1, sorta by assuming it's a gateway.

Comment: Could you post the windows routing and arp tables to help with troubleshooting please?

Comment: @Debra You can post it as answer for marking this problem as solved. It is a firewall problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the obvious: did you check that the Windows Firewall is disabled, and no "security" software on the Win machine is intervening? And did you check that the 10.10.10.1 interface is live?